# Posting new targets to vuforia with Python

Tags: python, vuforia

I'm trying to make a cms with Python to post new targets to a cloud database on vuforia. I found this Python library "[python-vuforia](https://github.com/j-white/python-vuforia)" but it has read functionalities only.
I added a function to post targets but so far getting 401 error. you can find the new function in [this commit](https://github.com/dadoeyad/python-vuforia/commit/2f1e3bf40863f9b3eafaf8f6867ce0f54c221e6e)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with this (commit)[https://github.com/dadoeyad/python-vuforia/commit/1997a49f94c5f2e13ab1d5c620c69160c76b7969]

I think the problem was with doing `str(req.get_data())` instead of `req.get_data()`
and `base64.b64encode(hmac(key, message, sha1).digest())` instead of `hmac(key, message, sha1).digest().encode('base64')`